# Как сделать деструкторизацию и применять несколько параметров сами обекты и props

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-hook, react-router-dom

Хочу получить значение numberArray и чтобы props, тоже работал, но когда пишу их вместе     numberArray равняется undefind.

```
     props,{numberArray}
```

вот так получаю.

```
const ReceivesDataInterface: React.FC<Propsinterface> = (props,{numberArray}) => {

    console.log(numberArray);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно сделать так

```
const ReceivesDataInterface: React.FC<Propsinterface> = ({numberArray, ...props}) => {

console.log(numberArray);
```